# Regex remove line contain character

Tags: regex

I have a list of values being returned to me and they all end with a | like below:

```
testdata1-old |
testdata |
test2-old|
```

I want to delete all the lines containing -old. What regex can I use?

Comment: What OS, environment, or programming language are you using?

Comment: windows, environment not sure what you mean but at the moment its in integration and language a java regEX would be good...kind of like this one I have "^.+?\SPM_.+$" but it obviously serves a different purpose

Comment: What's the input? What's the output? Is it a file? Is it used in a programming context with Java? Batch scripting?

Comment: the input is an xpath query that gives this output, its used within a programming context with java yes. So a print, write to file wont be appropiate. The only thing that would be acceptable is a regular expression. I got this "^.+\-old.+$" but its doing the opposite instead of deleting its keeping everything with -old

Answer (score 4):

I think you have a misunderstanding about regular expressions. Fundamentally they answer the question "does this text look like this particular pattern?" There are many tools that use regular expressions to manipulate text, like `sed` or `grep`, and I think you're confusing the two.

What you need to do is form a regular expression that matches the text you would like to filter. For example, the expression you're looking for is `^.*-old\|$`, and filter the lines using something like this.

```
foreach line in input_file
    if regex.matches(line, "^.*-old\|$") then
        continue
    else
        print line
```

Comment: Okay I am new to all this so i get my terms mixed up, I tried the expression on its own and it doesnt do anything its not removing the lines with -old. I

Comment: I have tried this regex "^.+\-old.+$" but instead of deleting those lines its keeping them

Comment: I second that, regex expressions are used to "answer the question", or rather describe the pattern. They obviously can't be the ones asking the question! ;-) If anything, it's the interpreter that asks the question "what do you want me to look for?".

Comment: Okay so what can i use to filter this and get the desired result of having all the lines containing -old removed

Comment: @user3738022 The pseudo code that Nat provided will print out all the lines that _don't_ match the regex. If you want to be able to return it to another function in Java, you can create a [StringBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) and append `line` to it in the `else` clause instead of printing.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is

> grep -v -E '^.*-old\|$' input_file > output_file

or what should work the same:

> egrep -v '^.*-old\|$' input_file > output_file

Now, the hard part is to find a windows version of `grep` or `egrep` that runs from either cmd.exe or Powershell.

Comment: Thank you but like you said the hard part find a windows version for grrp or egrep I dont want to use cmd and powershell. Can i not just change this command round so it deletes lines with old instead of selecting only those :^.+?\-old.+$

Comment: http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html - `negative lokahead` might work, depending on your regex engine.